# How to send image and charts using mailapp?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send an image and spreadsheet chart in an email together but I can only send one or the other. For example, i can only send images and the chart will not appear and if i send charts the images will not appear. I'm also new to this, thanks for the help.

```
{
function emailCharts(sheet,emails,emailSubject){
  DriveApp.getRootFolder()
var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Active spreadsheet of the key file
var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Test'); // Change the sheet name Eg.'IPQC Overall Tracker' to your sheet name
var emailSubject = 'Scratches Awareness Program Test';
var emails = 'example@gmail.com'; // your email ID
var charts = sheet.getCharts();

if(charts.length==0){
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: emails,
subject: "ERROR:"+emailSubject,
htmlBody: "No charts in the spreadsheet"});    
return;
}

var emailStarting = "<br>@@@@@@@@TEST@@@@@@@@@@<br>"
var emailEnding = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@<br>"
var emailSignature = "<br>Best Regards, <br>@@@@@@@@@@@@<br><br> This is an automated generated email. No signature is required."
var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length); 
var emailBody="Hi Everyone,<br>" + emailStarting;
var emailImages={};
for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
var builder = charts[i].modify();
builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
var newchart = builder.build();
chartBlobs[i]= newchart.getAs('image/png');
emailBody= emailBody + "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'></p>" ;
emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
}
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();

var requestData = {"method": "GET",
"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
   var googleLogoUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/vO6IJVG.png";
  var youtubeLogoUrl =
        "https://i.imgur.com/xMqvjHf.jpg";
  var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                         .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                         .getBlob()
                         .setName("Scratches Alert");
  var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                          .fetch(youtubeLogoUrl)
                          .getBlob()
                          .setName("Scratches Dashboard");

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: emails,
subject: emailSubject,
htmlBody: emailBody + emailEnding + emailSignature,
inlineImages:emailImages, attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}],googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob});
}
}
```

Comment: What is `googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob` at `MailApp.sendEmail()`? Can you provide the result you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: i did this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage . It sends 2 images in the email but i want it to also send 3 charts from my google spreadsheet along with the 2 images

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, `inlineImages` and `attachments` are used. You want to send the images of charts, `googleLogoBlob` and `youtubeLogoBlob` as `inlineImages`, and want to send Excel file as `attachments`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to send the images of charts, `googleLogoBlob` and `youtubeLogoBlob` as the inline images, and want to send Excel file (xlsx format) as the attachment file.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modification points:

- `format=xlsx` is used for converting Google Spreadsheet to Excel.

  - `{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}` is used as the attachment file.
  - Please modify to `{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL}`.
- `googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob` is directly used as the object for `MailApp.sendEmail(object)`. And `googleLogo` and `youtubeLogo` are not included in the inline images.

  - Please include those image to the inline images.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
   var googleLogoUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/vO6IJVG.png";
  var youtubeLogoUrl =
        "https://i.imgur.com/xMqvjHf.jpg";
  var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                         .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                         .getBlob()
                         .setName("Scratches Alert");
  var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                          .fetch(youtubeLogoUrl)
                          .getBlob()
                          .setName("Scratches Dashboard");

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: emails,
subject: emailSubject,
htmlBody: emailBody + emailEnding + emailSignature,
inlineImages:emailImages, attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}],googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob});
}
}
```

#### To:

```
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx"; // Modified
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  var googleLogoUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/vO6IJVG.png";
  var youtubeLogoUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/xMqvjHf.jpg";
  var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(googleLogoUrl).getBlob().setName("Scratches Alert");
  var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(youtubeLogoUrl).getBlob().setName("Scratches Dashboard");

  emailBody += "<img src='cid:googleLogo'><img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>"; // Added
  emailImages.googleLogo = googleLogoBlob; // Added
  emailImages.youtubeLogo = youtubeLogoBlob; // Added

  MailApp.sendEmail({ // Modified
    to: emails,
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: emailBody + emailEnding + emailSignature,
    inlineImages: emailImages,
    attachments: [{fileName: sheetName+".xlsx", content: contents, mimeType: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL}],
  });
}
```

### Note:

- About `googleLogo` and `youtubeLogo`, please modify `<img src='cid:googleLogo'><img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>` for your actual situation.

### References:

- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)
- [Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, you have been a great help. Just wondering is it possible to inline image a google slide so that whenever I send the automated email, it will send the updated slide?

Comment: @Alvis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your replying, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your goal. By posting it as new question, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve it, I'm glad. I would like to support you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the only isssue you are having is the way you're building your `MailApp.sendEmail()` . Do it in this way:

```
 var  emails = "example@gmail.com";
 var  emailSubject =  "Test Subject";
 var body = emailBody + emailEnding + emailSignature;
 var spreadsheetObj = {
    fileName:sheetName+".xls", 
    content:contents, 
    mimeType:"application//xls"
  };
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: emails,
     subject: emailSubject,
     htmlBody: body,
     attachments: [ spreadsheetObj, googleLogoBlob, youtubeLogoBlob]      
   });
```

The ***attachments*** must be an array, you were building it in the wrong way. As the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) says:

> attachments   BlobSource[] An array of files to send with the email (see example)

### Notice:

If you attach several files, the email can take some time to be delivered.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I need the googleLogoBlob and youtubeLogoBlob to be inline images and not as attachment. I tried this but my chart didnt appear as inline image as well.